# 400 Bad Request Nginx Apache

Tags: html, nginx, apache2, raspberry-pi

I am running Apache2 server on Raspberry pi 2 running osmc (based on Debian jessie).

I am occasionally getting 400 bad request errors (both with Firefox and Chrome), with Nginx written at the bottom. According to some advices I have found I should edit nginx configuration file so it will be able to take larger header files.

But I don't have Nginx installed at all. Could you please help me figure this out? When I google for answers, all I get is related to Nginx configuration.

Comment: I think you uri arguments receive some cann't to be parsed, like this a=%%123. So nginx cannot parse it, and return 400 bad request